# Video render is splitting the final video into chunks

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video

I'm totally new to Blender, specifically the video editing aspect to it, so I apologise in advance if I've missed something monumentally obvious.

Basically, I have edited together a video using multiple video, audio, and image files. I've managed to get everything looking, working, and sounding how I want. I've gone to render the video as a FFmpeg video, but when it renders, it gets about halfway through before splitting the video.

What I mean is, I can see where it is exporting it to (my dekstop), and it's one file, but at about 50% of the way in, it stops and begins to export the video into a second chunk, now a second file on my desktop. I rendered another video using the exact same technique the other day, which is roughly the same length, but that was only one file.

Please help!

Comment: Hello. Go to Render > Encoding and see if Autosplit Output is unchecked. Just a guess.

Comment: It was; I've unchecked it and have begun rendering again. Fingers crossed...?

Comment: Thanks @LeoNas that was the problem! Phew, got me worried there, although I don't know how it became checked between finishing one video and rendering the next, as I didn't alter any render properties.

Comment: Posting my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Render > Encoding and see if Autosplit Output is unchecked.

[image]